# Live Data with custom data class in kotlin android giving null

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I am using a custom data class in my ViewModel like this

```
class MainViewModel(val initialvalue:MainModel): ViewModel() {
    var countLiveData: MutableLiveData<MainModel>

    init {
        countLiveData = MutableLiveData<MainModel>()
        countLiveData.value = MainModel("hi","hm")
    }

    fun increment(){
        countLiveData.value?.two = countLiveData.value?.two + " Br"
    }
}
```

And this is my data class

```
data class MainModel(var one:String?, var two:String?)
```

and this is main activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel
    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

        // 2. add viewModel
        mainViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, MainViewModelFactory(MainModel("One String","String Two"))).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this

        binding.datamodel = mainViewModel

        // 1. add life cycle observer
        lifecycle.addObserver(MainObserver())
    }
}
```

**But the problem is that the live changes are not reflecting when i am changing the variables data 'one' and 'two' using editext?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you modify MainModel live data doesn't know about it and don't send notification.
To send notification you have to change countLiveData.value.

Try something like this

```
fun increment(){
    val value = countLiveData.value!!
    countLiveData.value = value.copy(two = value.two + " Br")
}
```

Comment: But i am updating variables using editext but still not working

Comment: I don't see it in the code sample

Comment: I am doing that with the help of two way data binding

Comment: To get updated value on observer you need to have separate LiveData for each edit text with LiveData type of String, Though if you try to evaluate your existing live data after adding some text in edit text it will be there in your model which is held by LiveData.

Answer (score 0):

> But the problem is that the live changes are not reflecting when i am changing the variables data 'one' and 'two' using editext?

In order to get the values to update when bound to EditTexts, the values themselves need to be observable types (like `LiveData`).

Right now `one` and `two` are just plain `Strings` - changing their value in no way notifies `Databinding` that they need to be rebound to the UI.

Your `ViewModel` should not have a nested view model that holds data - your `ViewModel` should expose observable data that `DataBinding` can observe and update:

```
class MainViewModel(val initialvalue:MainModel): ViewModel() {
    //var countLiveData: MutableLiveData<MainModel>
    var oneLiveData: MutableLiveData<String>()
    var twoLiveData: MutableLiveData<String>()    

    init {
        //countLiveData = MutableLiveData<MainModel>()
        //countLiveData.value = MainModel("hi","hm")
        oneLiveData.value = "hi"
        twoLiveData.value = "hm"
    }

    fun increment(){
        //countLiveData.value?.two = countLiveData.value?.two + " Br"
        twoLiveData.value = twoLiveData.value + " Br"
    }
}
```

If you want to keep the nested "MainModel" for some reason, it's attributes need to be observable types instead.

```
data class MainModel(var one:MutableLiveData<String>, var two:MutableLiveData<String>)
```